# Derivation of Ln root

Tags: derivatives

$$f(x) = \ln \sqrt{4x-3}$$
I'm practicing derivation for the exam and I'm stuck on this task. Could someone help me out in solving this. But when it comes to root, I'm a bit confused. The result is supposed to be $\frac2{4x-3}$.

I know for example if it were $f(x)=\ln(x^5)$, I would know how to solve it and get the result which is 
$$f'(x) = \frac1{x^5} \cdot 5x^4 = \frac5x$$

Comment: For $4x-3>0,$ $$\ln(4x-3)^{1/2}=\dfrac{\ln(4x-3)}2$$

Comment: Ooooh, that's what I needed okay thanks :P

Comment: @AlexR, Look at OP's comment

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, when $4x-3=0$, $\ln\left((4x-3)^{1/2}\right)$ is undefined.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Not sure what OP has to do with this. It was more about readability than about correctness. Nevermind. I'm deleting the comment since it's too late anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it without simplifying first, you can apply the chain rule two times:
$$f'(x) = \underbrace{\frac1{\sqrt{4x-3}}}_{= \ln'\sqrt{4x-3}} \cdot \underbrace{\frac1{2\sqrt{4x-3}}}_{= \sqrt{\ \ }' (4x-3)} \cdot \underbrace{4}_{= (4x-3)'} = \frac2{4x-3}$$
Using the simplification, it's only one chain rule
$$f'(x) = \underbrace{\frac12}_{\text{const.}} \cdot \underbrace{\frac1{4x-3}}_{\ln'(4x-3)} \cdot \underbrace{4}_{(4x-3)'} = \frac2{4x-3}$$